# Python Pyglet.window.Window() Seg Fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyglet

I am just working on bringing up a blank black box.  Super basic, but I keep getting a seg fault.

```
import pyglet

print("1\n")
#Create window
win = pyglet.window.Window()

print("2\n")

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()

print("3\n")
pyglet.app.run()`
```

I have inputted print statements to figure out where the seg fault begins... and it faults right at the win line.

(this is not my code it is from the tutorial site: https://greendalecs.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/3d-programming-in-python-part-1/)

Comment: Probably, this is due to a bug in the `pyglet` module. What OS are you using? You may need to talk to the module authors directly. If you can't get it to work, I recommend [Panda3d](https://www.panda3d.org/). It's well supported, and has a lot of documentation.

Comment: What error is reported to you?

Comment: Error:python main.py
1

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I am using Fedora...